# rotate (deskew) image with white background

Tags: c++, opencv

Here I have the part of a deskew class.. If/when the image is rotated it ends up like this. How to add a white background "behind" the rotated image?

[image]

## code

```
void Deskew::rotate(cv::Mat& im, double thetaRad){
    double rskew = thetaRad * CV_PI / 180;
    double nw = std::abs(sin(thetaRad)) * im.rows + std::abs(cos(thetaRad)) * im.cols;
    double nh = std::abs(cos(thetaRad)) * im.rows + std::abs(sin(thetaRad)) * im.cols;
    cv::Mat rot_mat = cv::getRotationMatrix2D(cv::Point2d(nw * 0.5, nh * 0.5), thetaRad * 180 / CV_PI, 1);
    cv::Mat pos = cv::Mat::zeros(cv::Size(1, 3), CV_64FC1);
    pos.at<double>(0) = (nw - im.cols) * 0.5;
    pos.at<double>(1) = (nh - im.rows) * 0.5;
    cv::Mat res = rot_mat * pos;
    rot_mat.at<double>(0, 2) += res.at<double>(0);
    rot_mat.at<double>(1, 2) += res.at<double>(1);
    cv::warpAffine(im, im, rot_mat, cv::Size(nw, nh), cv::INTER_LANCZOS4);
}
```

Comment: cv::warpAffine(im, im, rot_mat, cv::Size(nw, nh), cv::INTER_LANCZOS4,
              cv::BORDER_CONSTANT, 
              cv::Scalar(255, 255, 255) );

Comment: This code gives the same result :(

Comment: Are you able to provide a working example with the test image, which reproduces the problem ?

Comment: @SaharshBishnoi works for me ;D

Comment: @SaharshBishnoi create an answer :D